# Associations on Multilevel inheritance On STI rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, sti

I have 3 models in the hierarchy. User > Buyer > CoApplicant. If I add `has_many` associations in Buyer. It doesn't work with CoApplicant only with Buyer. But if I add `has_many` association in User it works for both for Buyer and CoApplicant. Is there any way I can declare the association in Buyer so it restricted to Buyer and CoApplicant.

Comment: What _exactly_ do your models look like? You have not provided any code or shown what you have tried.

Comment: What are your has_many associations?